Calculating the Volume with three given expression
How can I find the volume of the region defined by the expressions $z+x+y=180$, $40≤x≤100$ and $20≤y≤80$? I tried dividing this volume into familiar shapes (rectangular prism and triangular prism) but after a while I started to get confused. If manual calculation is not feasible, I'm open to solutions which uses a program or code to find this volume.

@StéphaneJaouen Is it better now? I am new in this website so I dont know many rules, thanks for clarification.

@StéphaneJaouen I recently finished Calculus 1. I dont know multivariable calculus sir.

The volume is defined by the equality $z + x + y = 180$? As in, you're looking at a subset of this plane? Then the volume is $0$. Or are you looking at $z + x + y \ge 180$? Or $z + x + y \le 180$? In either case, the region is unbounded, and the volume is infinite. This question really sounds like it is designed to be tackled with double integration, because if asked in that context, one could infer from said context that you'd need to include $0 \le z \le 180 - x - y$. All of this is to ask: where did you get this question, and why do you need a method of solving it without integration?

You say : "I don't know multivariable calculus". This might be a good opportunity to learn a little bit. But to do this, you have to do things in order and make reminders about the single-variable calculation.
Let's take an example: the area $\mathcal A$ of the trapezoid defined in the $xy$-plane by $$x+y\leq 10,4\leq x\leq 8, y\geq 0$$

We know that $$\mathcal A=\int_{4}^{8}(10-x)dx$$

For a volume like yours (with the clarifications of @Theo Bendit), integral calculus is similarly adapted. We start by setting $x_0$ between $40$ and $100$; then we calculate the area $\mathcal A(x_0)$ of the slice associated to $x_0$ $$\color{blue}{\mathcal A(x_0)=\int_{20}^{80} (180 - x_0 - y) dy}$$
Then we vary $x_0$ again to get the volume$$\displaystyle \int_{40}^{100} \color{blue}{\mathcal A(x)} dx$$

What @Hosam Hajeer summed up for you in the formula $$V= \displaystyle \int_{40}^{100}\color{blue}{[ \int_{20}^{80} (180 - x - y) dy]} dx$$

This is the kind of region we are interested in, as you understood from your post

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cdisplaystyle+%5Cint_%7B40%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%5Cint_%7B20%7D%5E%7B80%7D+%28180+-+x+-+y%29+dy+dx (coherent with @Bob Dobbs)

Without calculus...
This is a trapezodial prism. The cross-section at $x=40$ is the trapezoid $y+z=140$, $20\leq y\leq 80$. Its area is $A_1=\tfrac{z_1+z_2}2(y_2-y_1)=\tfrac{120+60}2(80-20)=5400.$ Similarly the cross-section area at $x=100$ is $A_2=1800.$ Hence, the volume of the prism is $V=\tfrac{A_1+A_2}2(x_2-x_1)=\tfrac{5400+1800}2(100-40)=60^3.$

Maybe that's the best answer, right? And besides, "without calculus" is a good joke :)))
